# Camel consuming large file encoded with base64

Tags: file, stream, base64, apache-camel

I'm trying to read a large file with apache camel. The content of the file is base64 encoded and I want to decode this. Reading a large ASCII-based text file is no problem, but this one...

In this case I cannot split it at the end of a line, because the base64 line end is not the line end of my data (the data is csv). Later I want do manipulate the data.

With following camel route it works, but so the file have to exist and is not locked, when the route starts, else I get an IllegalArgumentException. But I don't know, when the file will exist.

EDIT: I forgot: camel-version: 2.14.1 | java: 1.7

I need a solution for my promblen, can someone help me?

```
from("stream:file?fileName=/path/to/file&scanStream=true")
                .routeId(ROUTE_ID_BASE64)
                .unmarshal().base64()
                .setHeader("foo", constant("foo"))
                .aggregate(header("foo"), new StringBodyAggregator())
                .completionSize(1000)
                .completionTimeout(1500) 
                .to("file:" + this.tempPfad + "?fileName=" + this.tempDateiname + "&charset=utf-8&fileExist=Append");
```

I tried also:

```
from("file:" + this.eingabePfad + "?filter=#dateinamenFilter&maxDepth=1&readLock=changed&noop=true&charset=utf-8")
                .routeId(ROUTE_ID_BASE64)
                .unmarshal().base64()
                .setHeader("foo", constant("foo"))
                .aggregate(header("foo"), new StringBodyAggregator())
                .completionSize(1000)
                .completionTimeout(1500)
                .to("file:" + this.tempPfad + "?fileName=" + this.tempDateiname + "&charset=utf-8&fileExist=Append");
```

But then I get following error:

```
ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-smith-52872-1421933301634-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-smith-52872-1421933301634-0-3). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 2 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: /path/to/temp/tempDatei.csv. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[DelegateSync[yy.xxxxx.myproject.routes.DateiPolling$1@5734ea]]]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[routeBase64       ] [routeBase64       ] [file:///path/to/?charset=utf-8&filter=%23datein] [      1998]
[routeBase64       ] [unmarshal2        ] [unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.Base64DataFormat@153097e]         ] [         5]
[routeBase64       ] [setHeader1        ] [setHeader[foo]                                                                ] [         0]
[routeBase64       ] [aggregate1        ] [aggregate[header(foo)]                                                        ] [         0]
[routeBase64       ] [to1               ] [file:/path/to/temp/?fileName=tempDatei.csv&char] [        24]
[                  ] [process1          ] [yy.xxxxx.myproject.routes.DateiPolling$1@5734ea                     ] [        15]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-smith-52872-1421933301634-0-3
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-smith-52872-1421933301634-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=/path/to/base64File.txt, CamelFileLastModified=1417777182000, CamelFileLength=267439971, CamelFileName=base64File.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=base64File.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=base64File.txt, CamelFileParent=/path/to, CamelFilePath=/path/to/base64File.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=base64File.txt, CamelRedelivered=true, CamelRedeliveryCounter=1, CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter=1, foo=foo}
    BodyType            org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream
    Body                [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]
]
```

`Stacktrace
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: /path/to/temp/tempDatei.csv
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:276)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$1.run(AggregateProcessor.java:548)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.SynchronousExecutorService.execute(SynchronousExecutorService.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.onSubmitCompletion(AggregateProcessor.java:540)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.access$900(AggregateProcessor.java:82)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.onEviction(AggregateProcessor.java:853)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.onEviction(AggregateProcessor.java:814)
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.purge(AggregateProcessor.java:826)
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:115)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:172)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter$1.read(IOConverter.java:83)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BaseNCodecInputStream.read(BaseNCodecInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:203)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:224)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByReaderWithCharset(FileOperations.java:402)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:266)
        ... 29 more
    2015-01-22 14:28:26,113 [eTimeoutChecker] AggregateProcessor                            WARN  Error processing aggregated exchange. Exchange[base64File.txt]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot store file: /path/to/temp/tempDatei.csv]
    org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: /path/to/temp/tempDatei.csv
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:276)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$1.run(AggregateProcessor.java:548)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.SynchronousExecutorService.execute(SynchronousExecutorService.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.onSubmitCompletion(AggregateProcessor.java:540)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.access$900(AggregateProcessor.java:82)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.onEviction(AggregateProcessor.java:853)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.onEviction(AggregateProcessor.java:814)
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor$AggregationTimeoutMap.purge(AggregateProcessor.java:826)
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:115)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:172)
        at org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter$1.read(IOConverter.java:83)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BaseNCodecInputStream.read(BaseNCodecInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:203)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:224)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByReaderWithCharset(FileOperations.java:402)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:266)
        ... 29 more`

Comment: Does the directory /path/to/temp/tempDatei.csv exist? It looks a little suspicious to me.

Comment: The directory does exist. The try with "from("stream:..." writes without problems in this directoy and file. The producer in both examples the same.

Comment: I see some of the exception related to the `[eTimeoutChecker]` could it be timing out?

Comment: [eTimeoutChecker]  ist part of the aggregation  and .completionTimeout(1500). I will try it without this.

Comment: Without aggregation, the part with the AggregateProcessor and follow up is not part of the stacktrace anymore, but the problem still exists.

Comment: The proplem was sitting 50cm in front of the monitor, as always ;)

Comment: Aaah the old Problem In Chair Not In Computer (PICNIC) error. Happens to the best of us. Glad it was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With adding the line

```
.split().tokenize(LINE_SEPARATOR).streaming()
```

it works now. Important is

```
.end()
```

at the end of the route, and not direct after the unmarshalling.

I changed also the Aggregatorstrategy from String to byte[], to prevent errors with UTF-8 encoding.

The complete route:

```
from("file:" + this.eingabePfad + "?filter=#dateinamenFilter&maxDepth=1&readLock=changed&noop=true")
                .routeId(ROUTE_ID_BASE64)
                .split().tokenize(LINE_SEPARATOR).streaming()
                .unmarshal().base64()
                .setHeader("foo", constant("foo"))
                .aggregate(header("foo"), new ByteArrayBodyAggregator())
                .completionSize(1000)
                .completionTimeout(1500)
                .to("file:" + this.tempPfad + "?fileName=" + this.tempDateiname + "&charset=utf-8&fileExist=Append")
                .end();
```